# Sending specific keypresses over USB or Bluetooth to another PC

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, bluetooth

I wish to make my laptop think im pressing alt when I press it on my desktop so I can use it to do push to talk on my laptop when im playing games, but not use a voice chat on my desktop, i've checked google but couldnt find anything from what i searched.
Can use bluetooth or USB but I don't have any devices that I can program to do it.